# How do I hide or rename Google Drive connected server icons on macOS?

Tags: google-apps

How do I hide or rename the Google server icons from my macOS desktop (other than hiding all other "connected servers" with the Finder setting as well)? With multiple accounts, the Google Drive icons make a mess of my otherwise tidy Desktop.

Comment: As far as I can see, this question is perfectly on-topic on AD.

Comment: @nohillside But the question is really about what I can do on the Google Drive side of things. There's nothing particular to do on the Apple end (e.g., the Finder setting, which affects all connected servers).

Comment: People on WebApps SE seem to think that it's off-topic there (and while I'm not familiar with all the rules there, https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic indicates this as well). Google Drive is "just" an application after all.

Comment: @nohillside I'm happy to be proved wrong, but I don't think it will get an answer here.

Comment: This might very well be, maybe there just is no answer to this. But this doesn‘t make it on-topic on WebApps SE. If you think it should be on-topic there, please raise it on *their* Meta site.